# calculate interval of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How do I calculate the interval of convergence of $$ \frac{1+x}{1-x} $$

I made it into a taylor series expansion using first principles and the sum is this $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left( \{ \begin{gather} 1\ when\ n=0\\ 2\ when\ n>0 \end{gather}\right) x^n$$ and afterwards I tried using the ratio test for $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2x^n$ $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{2x^{(n+1)}}{2x^n}\right|=|x| $$ afterwards can I just say the interval of convergence is $|x|<1$ ?? but I used wolfram alpha and it said the series diverges. So did I do it correctly? Or am I missing something?

Comment: That is not written in series yet. I suggest rewriting it as

$$\frac{1}{1-x} + x \frac{1}{1-x},$$

writing $1/1-x$ as a series, collect terms and alike and only then apply convergence tests.

Comment: Convergence...of a function?? Its definition domain is $\;\{x\in\Bbb C\;;\;x\neq 1\}\;$ , but "convergence interval" means nothing here as you don't have a power series.

Comment: @Fantini you mean I apply convergence tests on each separately?

Comment: @StefanSmith I've already edited it. I think I am supposed to expand it into a series myself.

Comment: @DonAntonio I've already made it into a series by expanding it with mclaurin series expansion

Comment: @user115636 : Thanks.  When I posted my comment there was no series in your question.  Usually when make such a request of a poster of a question, they ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "first principles," but here's an approach you can take.

To start with, note that $$f(x):=\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\frac{2-1+x}{1-x}=\frac{2-(1-x)}{1-x}=\frac2{1-x}-1.$$ It is readily shown that $f(0)=1,$ and that for $n\ge 1,$ we have $$f^{(n)}(0)=n!\cdot 2,$$ so that the Taylor series for $f(x)$ about $x=0$ is given by $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n,$$ where $$a_n=\begin{cases}1 & n=0\\2 & n\ge 1.\end{cases}$$ Then we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac22\right|=1,$$ and so the radius of convergence is $\frac11=1,$ as you claimed. Note that [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor+Series+of+%281%2Bx%29%2F%281-x%29+about+x%3D0) confirms convergence when $|x|<1.$